# Question - is there a simple example end-to-end dApp on Cardano

Tags: decentralized-applications

as the title says... is there any example of a simple application built on cardano? I tried to find one but apparently there is none. I want to start learning by interacting directly through code and learn on the way.

If someone already wrote a "hello world" application with a front and back end interacting with cardano's blockchain, please share your github repo.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Plutus Pioneer's lecture notes](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#). It is a whole series of lectures and exercises to help beginners get started with Cardano smart contracts. There is even one exercise titled "[HelloWorld Script](https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alonzo/hello_world_script.html)". In addition to this there are [video supplements](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnPTB0CuBOBypVDf1oGcsvnJGJg8h-LII) by Lars Brunjes, IOHK's director of education.